# How to fetch json data array from API

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin

I am working in **Android studio** and using **Kotlin**. I am trying to fetch json data from **open trivia database**. This is my classes for handling the request and response:

```
class TriviaRequest (

    val results: List<TriviaResult>
)

class TriviaResult(

    val category: String,
    val type: String,
    val question: String,
    val correct_answer: String,
    val incorrect_answer: List<String>
)
```

This is how the json data looks like:

```
{"response_code":0,"results":[{"category":"General 
Knowledge","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"What is the nickname of the US state of 
California?","correct_answer":"Golden State","incorrect_answers":["Sunshine State","Bay 
State","Treasure State"]}]}
```

And this is my code for fetching the data:

```
 private fun fetch(){

    Log.d("fetch", "fetching")
    val url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple"
    Log.d("url", "url='" + url + "'")
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build()
    Log.d("request", request.toString())
    Log.d("client", client.toString())
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

            val body = response.body?.string()
            Log.d("body", body)
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val triviaRequest = gson.fromJson(body, TriviaRequest::class.java)
            val result = triviaRequest.results[0]
            val question = result.question.toSpanned()
            Log.d("question", question.toString())
            val questionCategory = result.category.toSpanned()
            Log.d("category", questionCategory.toString())
            val correctAnswer = result.correct_answer.toSpanned()
            Log.d("correct", correctAnswer.toString())
            try {
                val incorrectAnswers = result.incorrect_answer[0].toSpanned()
                Log.d("incorrect", incorrectAnswers.toString())

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
```

This is my toSpanned function:

```
fun String.toSpanned() : Spanned {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(this, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        return Html.fromHtml(this)
    }
}
```

My *question*, *category* and *correctAnswer* works fine but when this code executes:

*val incorrectAnswers = result.incorrect_answer[0].toSpanned()*

This **exception** occurs:

> W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: make your _TriviaRequest_ class into **data class TriviaRequest**

Comment: Tried it but it gives the same errror... @USMANosman

Comment: in your data class you've spelling mistake incorrect_answer contain 's' at the end, it should be **incorrect_answers**

Comment: omg that was it! one letter short... Thanks! @USMANosman

Comment: but if you are uncomfortable with variables name you can use SearializedName which helps you to name your variable whatever you want but searalizedName should be match with your Json data variables

Comment: Okey will look it up! :) @USMANosman